# Adding a form to a button

Tags: html, css, perl

I am new to programming and I was wondering if anyone can help me with this simple task. I am currently programming in perl to display this webpage. I need help adding a form that the user will fill out once they click the "add comment" button. I attached a photo of what the form should look like. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me so I can finish my webpage.

Form:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of how the webpage looks like:
[image]

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST GET);
use CGI qw/:standard /;
use DBI;

$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:ODBC:SMSDWDE2','BLANK','Blank',{RaiseError =>1, AutoCommit=>1});
my $q = new CGI();
print $q->header;
print $q->start_html(-head=>meta({-http_equiv => 'X-UA-Compatible',
                       -content=>'IE=edge,chrome=1'}),

                       -style => {'src'=>'css/eq - Copy1.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/animate/animate.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/select2/select2.min.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'css/util.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'css/main.css'},
                                      -script =>{'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'js/main.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/select2/select2.min.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js'},

                                 -title=>'MET IN PHOTO');

print "             
<div id='wrapper'>
        <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target=''.navbar-ex1-collapse'>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </button>
                <a class='logo' href='#'>
                    <img src='images/ti-logo.png' alt='CoolAdmin' />
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse'>
                <ul id='active' class='nav navbar-nav side-nav'>
                    
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsMet.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> METROLOGY - 48Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsMet-96hrs.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> METROLOGY - 96Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsCMPIMP1.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> CMP/IMP - 48Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsCMPIMP1-96hrs.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> CMP/IMP - 96 Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsDIFFWET.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> DIFF/WET - 48Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsDIFFWET-96hrs.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> DIFF/WET - 96 Hrs</a></li>

                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPHOTO.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PHOTO - 48Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPHOTO-96hrs.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PHOTO - 96 Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPLASMA.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PLASMA - 48Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPLASMA-96hrs.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PLASMA - 96 Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsTHINFILM.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> THINFILM - 48Hrs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsTHINFILM-96hrs.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> THINFILM - 96 Hrs</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user'>
                    <li class='divider-vertical'></li>
                    <li>
                        <form class='navbar-search'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Search' class='form-control'>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id='page-wrapper'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <h1>Critical Dashboard <small>Metrology - 48Hrs</small></h1>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
                
                
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading'>
                            <h3 class='panel-title'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o'></i> Fab Dashboard - DMOS5 </h3>
                        </div>
                        
                        <table class='table'>
                            <thead>

                            <tr>
                                    <th>ZUM_TOOL_GROUP</th>
                                    <th>MISTI</th>
                                    <th>STATE</th>
                                    <th>HRS</th>
                                    <th>COMMENTS<th>
                                    <th>ADD COMMENTS<th>
                                   
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                    </div>";
                    
$sqlstr="Select 
      CASE WHEN g.entity like 'AM101%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'
WHEN g.entity like 'AM103%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'
WHEN g.entity like 'AM104%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'
WHEN g.entity like 'AM105%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'
WHEN g.entity like 'AM106%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'
WHEN g.entity like 'AM107%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'                   
WHEN g.entity like 'AM108%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'                   
WHEN g.entity like 'AMX01%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'
WHEN g.entity like 'AMX02%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'                   
WHEN g.entity like 'AMX03%' then 'KLA 5100 5200 Archer Alignment Overlay 200'
WHEN g.entity like 'IN104%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'IN107%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'IN110%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'IN112%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'IN113%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'IN114%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'INS01%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'INS02%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'INS03%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'INS04%' then 'KT Bright Field Inspection'
WHEN g.entity like 'SS301%' then 'Daifuku Cleanway AMHS 200'                
         ELSE 'NONE'
       end as ZUM_TOOL_GROUP,
       g.entity as MISTI,
       t.cur_state      as STATE,
       ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) AS HRS

From Entity_Grp_Lst g
left outer join trk_id_def t
on g.facility = t.facility
and g.grp_type = t.grp_type
and g.entity=t.entity
and g.grp_type = '720'
WHERE t.cur_state NOT IN ('PROD','NM','TERM','NULL','IDLE', 'YER', 'I05', 'I07', 'TFKT', 'EMOD', 'DVLP', 'MFGM', 'PENG', 'EENG', 'MDLE', 'HDLE')
and Entity_Grp_type = '041'
and g.ENTITY_GRP in ('MET')
and (g.entity like 'AM101%' or
g.entity like 'AM103%' or
g.entity like 'AM104%' or
g.entity like 'AM105%' or
g.entity like 'AM106%' or
g.entity like 'AM107%' or                   
g.entity like 'AM108%' or                   
g.entity like 'AMX01%' or
g.entity like 'AMX02%' or                   
g.entity like 'AMX03%' or
g.entity like 'IN104%' or
g.entity like 'IN107%' or
g.entity like 'IN110%' or
g.entity like 'IN112%' or
g.entity like 'IN113%' or
g.entity like 'IN114%' or
g.entity like 'INS01%' or
g.entity like 'INS02%' or
g.entity like 'INS03%' or
g.entity like 'INS04%' or
g.entity like 'SS301%')

AND ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) >= 48  
order by ZUM_TOOL_GROUP ASC

";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlstr);
$sth->execute();
$sth->bind_columns(undef, \$ZUM_TOOL_GROUP, \$MISTI, \$STATE, \$HRS);




while($sth->fetch()) {
    

   print "
                    
                            <tbody>
                            
                                <tr class='row100 body'>
                                    <td class='cell100 column1'><input type='checkbox'/>$ZUM_TOOL_GROUP</td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column2'><FORM ACTION='http://d5lxgenwebapp01z.dal.make.ti.com/get_de1_de2_misti_comments.pl' METHOD='POST' target='_blank' NAME='userInput2'>
        <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='eq' MAXLENGTH='8' VALUE='$MISTI'>
              <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='pages' SIZE='3' MAXLENGTH='2' VALUE='50'>
        <INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit' VALUE='$MISTI'></form></td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column3 $STATE'>$STATE</td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column4'>$HRS</td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column5'></td>
                                    <td><input class='btn btn-warning add-comment-btn'  type='button' value='Add Comment'/></td>
                                    
                                </tr>

   </tr>";
}

print "</tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <p >Email: <a href='mailto:med@blank.com?subject=CRITICAL TOOLS DASHBOARD WEBPAGE'>Med</a></p>
                </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

print "


</body></html>";
```

Comment: This question is kind of vague. It looks like you are probably using Perl to print out your webpack. I would add context like "I'm using Perl" so that people can scan and know if they are able to help.

Comment: Hi @JakeAve thank you for the feedback! I will update it right now.

Comment: Do you want the form to appear as a pop-up or on a separate page?

Comment: @DaveCross popup

Comment: @DaveCross a pop-up